# How to view metadata of ArcGIS World Imagery Clarity?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, world-imagery

I want to see the year and resolution for certain areas for the World Imagery Clarity.

Clarity: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ab399b847323487dba26809bf11ea91a

Now, it seems there is some kind of existing layer, but when I load it into ArcGIS Pro, it doesn't seem to work. Nothing comes up besides the imagery and the street overlay.

Existing (broken) metadata: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=298f03f7f02c465a87bcf817c3b8859b

I was hoping for something more like this: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018129

The above link is for metadata for the World Imagery Classic, not for Clarity. I wish I could get a polygon like that for Clarity. That is my ideal format.

What I did find was ArcGIS Wayback, which is helpful, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for some kind of polygon metadata later for World Imagery Clarity.

ArcGIS Wayback: https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/wayback

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. The Identify tool does not provide the source date like it does with the original World Imagery Basemap.

Comment: I ended up calling ESRI tech support about this, but they said nothing like I described exists currently for the World Imagery Clarity. :/